# Permissions and admin approval of additions and edits

Tags: permissions, roles, workflow

I'm setting up an instance on Drupal for an organisation to use with delegated data entry roles. The main admin person would like a workflow step that requires her to approve any additions or edits to contact fields (entries in general would be fine). Is there a way to do this, perhaps with an extension? I don't see anything native in the CMS permissions or Civi ACLs aside from having the admin role periodically do a search for recent modifications and revert them if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility could be using a webform_civicrm form that is (somehow??) set up so that folk who enter the data can only 'save as draft' - hence the data is only stored in Drupal at that point - and (assuming I am not overlooking a big gotcha) this could then allow an admin to review/edit the draft and submit it which should then result in the data being pushed to civicrm.

A view could be built to show the data that is currently awaiting approval.

This may not be doable, but it could be worth exploring.

Comment: I like this idea, @petednz...using the CMS as interim datastore pending approval. Maybe I should try a proof of concept and see how it goes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not what you're looking for but if the data entry people make csv files with rows for what their adds/edits would be, then the admin can review the csv file and run an import to make the changes live. When you run an import as an update it has an option to leave any field as-is if it's left blank on the row, so they wouldn't have to fill out the whole row, just any edits.

Comment: nice idea Demerit

Comment: That sounds workable, and the manager certainly has good data hygiene skills so she probably would not mind working this way. Thanks for the suggestion.